# I keep getting an indent error no matter what I do, even when there is no indentation

Tags: python, indentation, cs50

I cannot figure this one out, no matter what I do. I keep getting the Unexpected Indent Error, no matter what I do with the spacing.

I've spent two days trying to fix it myself and find someone who can explain what is going on. I have included a screenshot of my [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) IDE because I feel that it best shows the error I am having.

[image: Original error]

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():

   if request.method == "POST":

       quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

       if quote == None:
           return apology ("invalid symbol", 400)


        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except:
            return apology("shares must be positive", 400)
```

[image: Updated error]

Comment: In the future, please post all code as text. `try` requires an `except` or `finally` block though, which you haven't supplied.

Comment: Add a tab and then remove it. Since it is a function, try to move it in a different position and see if the error is again on that function.

Comment: Your indentation is still wrong. Compare the `try` to the `if` above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'close' the `try` block with a `except`, i.e:

```
try:
    shares = (int(request.form.get("shares"))
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

---

Or skip the `try`, and use try-except when you know what type of error to expect, i.e:

```
shares = (int(request.form.get("shares"))
```

More information on try-except blocks is [here](https://www.techbeamers.com/use-try-except-python/#:%7E:text=Use%20an%20else%20clause%20right,run%20when%20no%20errors%20occurred.).

---

So the error about indentation is misleading. I have been there too :(